# edit value in inner array in nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I have the following NSmutableArray:

```
Printing description of globals->_info:
<__NSCFArray 0x8a979c0>(
{
    rep = "name";
    PriceA = 150;
    PriceB = 150;
    nextInvoice = 1001000001;
},
{
    rep = "othername";
    PriceA = 150;
    PriceB = 150;
    nextInvoice = 1001000001;
}
)
```

How do I increment by one the nextInvoice?

thanks!

Comment: So for which of the inner arrays do you want to increase the nextInvoice int by one? They would need to be mutable by the way. Also, those inner "arrays" look a lot like dictionaries...

Comment: How do you figure that the content in the array is array's?

Comment: I just figured, are they nsdictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one (immutable) array that contains two objects of the type of some dictionary. Assuming that the dictionaries are mutable then go for:

(assuming it is named outerArray)

```
NSMutableDictionary *innerDict = [outerArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *aNumber  = [innerDict objectForKey:@"nextInvoice"];
NSNumber *bNumber  = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [aNumber intValue] +1];
[innerDict setObject:bNumber forKey:@"nextInvoice"];
```

Depending on from where you come, this style may be easier to read: 
(Hope I get it right, don't use it often; If somebody finds an error - feel free to edit)

```
NSMutableDictionary *innerDict = outerArray [0];
NSNumber *aNumber  = innerDict [@"nextInvoice"];
NSNumber *bNumber  = @(aNumber intValue] +1);
innerDict[@"nextInvoice"] = bNumber;
```

But be aware that this only works when the inner dictionary within the outer array is actually mutable.

Comment: Thanks, it works. you have a typo on MutableDictionary and didn't close " after "next invoice" but thanks

Comment: Thanks. Mended the answer.

Comment: Still a typo in Dictioary instead of Dictionary :)

Answer (score 0):

Your inner objects are NSDictionaries as-well.

You could user NSMutableDictionary instead.

But I think it is time to create a own class and use instances of those in the array instead.

Comment: Why new class if it can be done in simple way your ans does not make any sense

Comment: @hussainShabbir, let me guess: you are usually to lazy to create a custom class? a class is a perfect way to create a model object. your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Creating Custom class is not required for.editing an array. So please better you delete your ans